# Residue for $\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}$ at zeros of $\zeta(2s).$

Tags: residue-calculus, riemann-zeta

I want to calculate residue at the poles for $\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}.$ For pole of numerator $s=1$ I have calculated the residue. I am having trouble at the zeros of denominator. Basically I am interested in this limit
$$ Res_{s= \frac{1}{2}\rho}\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)} = \lim_{s\to \frac{1}{2}\rho } \frac{(s- \frac{1}{2}\rho )\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}  $$ 
where $\rho$ are the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s).$

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If $f,g$ are holomorphic and $g$ has a simple zero at $z_0$, then the residue of $\dfrac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ at $z_0$ is $\dfrac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you.